# Cancel links from richEditBox

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[UWP] [C#] [XAML]

Hi, I have a richEditBox in which the user pastes some text, some times happens that the user pastes a link [of this tipe](http://www.example.com) and when I get the text from the richEditBox it is automatically converted to a string like this:

"`HYPERLINK "http://www.example.com"`"

Is it possible to get only the name of the link and not all this stuff?

For instance:

"My [example](http://www.example.com)"

should be converted to

"`My example`"

and not

"`My HYPERLINK "http://www.example.com"`"

Comment: I copy "My [example](http://www.example.com)" to the `RichEditBox`, it shows "My example". Could you show us your XAML code? Could you tell us your OS version of your Windows and your VS SDK?

Comment: @JaydenGu-MSFT Sure, I have the latest updates of Windows 10 and vs2017, to get the text form the RichEditBox I use this code:  `myRichEditBox.Document.GetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextGetOptions.UseLf, out myVariable);`, however, maybe I didn't explain well, when I paste the text it is shown in the right way, but when I get it and store it somewhere(variables... ) it is transformed in "HYPERLINK ..."